# Storing text document in java: memory usage

Tags: java, list, memory, arraylist

I want to write custom text area widget and for this I need to find good way to store text document. 
Since I need an ability to edit it, I need easy access to any line and char at any position.

Then my idea was to store document as list of list of chars: `List<List<Character>> lines` (using ArrayList implementation).

This approach works, I have easy access to line/char, but what surprises me the most is memory usage.

I have generated a file of 100 000 000 characters and loaded it into the structure.

```
List<List<Character>> lines = new ArrayList<List<Character>>();
List<Character> line;

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
for(String str; (str = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
    line = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) 
        line.add(c);

    lines.add(line);
}
```

100k characters takes **~1.1GB** of memory! I have compared it with C#, the same approach and it takes only ~350 MB.

Of course it is still a lot of memory, considering the fact `char` is 2 bytes in both Java/C#, then 100000000 chars = ~190MB and the rest is List/ArrayList memory.

I know Java is memory-eater, **but how it comes it takes so much memory in Java?** *(especially considering the fact C# takes only 350mb and both are the same level language)* **What could be better way to store a text document then?**

**Edit:**

Memory usage of `List<StringBuilder>`:

`Java`: ~500MB

`C#`: ~300MB

C# Code:

```
List<List<char>> lines = new List<List<char>>();
string str;
while ((str = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    List<char> line = new List<char>();

    foreach (char c in str)
        line.Add(c);

    lines.Add(line);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `Character` is a reference type, i.e. a pointer to a `Character` object on the heap. Each `Character` object has some memory overhead too. What's wrong with for instance `List<StringBuffer>`?

Comment: How did you compare with C#? Can you share details or if you ran code then can you share code...

Comment: You could also try a 2D array. Simply index it by `[lineNumber][linePosition]`. This would allow the use of primitive `char` types, which take less space.

Comment: @aioobe, well, nothing's wrong, I just didn't think of it. I have tested it and memory usage is much better (check updated post; though still C# wins, but with much smaller difference), thanks for the suggestion! Btw. does it mean *theoretically* if Java allowed primitives in List, memory usage would be better?

Comment: @hagrawal, my method probably is not very precise as I check memory usage in Task Manager, I have added used C# snippet.

Comment: @River, for text editor I need it to be flexible when it comes to size

Comment: As you are also aware, using task manager for heap size calculation is not a very reliable way, so I would recommend that better to use Java and C# APIs for the same and reach some conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `ArrayList<String>`.  you can access any char at any point in String using charAt(), and it is easy enough to insert more characters into a String.

Comment: Assuming you store each line as a `String`, this works.